# Como usar filtro 'Regex' do MongoDB no PHP

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, mongodb, nosql

Já fiz algumas tentativas seguindo exemplos na internet, encontrei alguns até que parece haver uma mistura das duas versões do driver

Atualmente, no banco do MongoDB tenho uma estrutura parecida com o exemplo seguinte:

```
{
   "@versao": "3.10",
   "Documento": {
      "@Id": "ABCD123456789"
   },
   "protDoc": {
      "@versao": "3.10",
      "infDoc": {
         "Amb": "1",
         "Chave": "545asd828322852",
         "dhRecbto": "2017-05-23T23:24:00-03:00",
         "nProt": "17894060",
         "digVal": "+zVS8UJBtNk2edU478TUya6vGXs=",
      }
   }
}
```

Minhas tentativas são de obter os documentos que contém certa parte do texto do campo '@Id', no Compass consigo filtrar usando o seguinte filtro

```
{'doc.Documento.@Id': {$regex : '123456789$'}} //Informo só parte do Id
```

No PHP, minha ultima tentativa foi seguir a documentação do MongoDB(https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/master/tutorial/crud/#regular-expressions). O Código está assim.

```
<?php
$conn = new MongoClient("mongodb://192.168.123.1:27017");
$collection = $conn->DB->colecao;

$cursor = $collection->find([
        'doc.Documento.@Id' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex('123456789$', 'i')
        ]);

var_dump($cursor) //Não há nada
```

Tentei usar os filtros de maneira diferentes mas não houve sucesso. Outra montagem que tinha feito anteriormente foi essa.

```
<?php
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://192.168.123.1:27017');

$filtro = ['doc.Documento.@Id' => ['$regex' => '123456789$']];
$opcoes = [];

$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filtro, $opcoes);

$documentos = $manager->executeQuery('DB.colecao', $query);
var_dump($documentos);//Não há nada
```

Qual seria a maneira correta para trazer os documentos filtrando parte do valor de um field?

Obs: Consigo trazer vários documento usando o find.

Já tentei seguir estes outros exemplos:

-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34707657/set-filter-with-regex-in-query-with-phps-mongodb-driver-query-class

-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45523046/mongodb-php-search-for-string-with-query

-http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.mongodb-driver-query.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver da seguinte maneira;

```
    $regex = new MongoDB\BSON\Regex(trim('123456789', '/'), 'i');

    $search = array('doc.Documento.@Id' => $regex);
    $options = [
    "skip" => 0,
    "limit" => 10,
    "projection" => []
    ];

    $query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($search, $options);
    $cursor = $manager->executeQuery('DataBase.Colection', $query);

    foreach ($cursor as $doc) {
       $doc = json_decode(json_encode($doc), true);
       var_dump($doc);
       break;
    }
```

Assim consigo todos os documentos no retorno.